# Why can't I use the null-coalescing operator like this?

Tags: c#, .net, guid

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

> The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to
>   define a default value for nullable value types or reference types.

But when I run the code below:

```
Guid test;
Guid otherGuid = test ?? Guid.NewGuid();
```

I get the error:

> Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Guid' and
>   'System.Guid'

I thought Guid was a reference type. Is that not the case?  Could someone explain to my why this does not work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Guid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) is not a reference type, its a **value type**, you can't assign it null and that is why you can't check it with `??`

Following line will give you error.

> Cannot convert null to 'System.Guid' because it is a non-nullable
>   value type

```
Guid test = null;
```

You may use [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)

```
Nullable<Guid> test = null;
Guid otherGuid = test ?? Guid.NewGuid();
```

Or short form

```
Guid? test = null;
Guid otherGuid = test ?? Guid.NewGuid();
```

Answer (score 7):

[`Guid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) is a struct and not a class, and can thus not be null.

For this to work, you could do something like this:

```
Guid? nullableGuid = null;
/* At some point nullableGuid is perhaps assigned... */
Guid otherGuid = nullableGuid ?? Guid.NewGuid();
```

Answer (score 4):

GUID is a structure. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx

Try using `Guid.Empty` to do the check.

```
Guid otherGuid = test == Guid.Empty ? Guid.NewGuid() : test;
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, Guid is a value type and not a reference type, see [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-value-type-and-reference-type) for a more in-depth explanation about the difference between the two. You'd have two options in your scenario.

1. **Coalescence operator:**

```cs
Guid? guid = null;
otherGuid = guid ?? Guid.NewGuid();
```

2. **[`default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default) comparison**

```cs
otherGuid = guid == default ? Guid.NewGuid() : guid;
```

In the second option you could also guse `Guid.Empty`, but using the `default` keyword would be better practice.